# Как грамотно задать бэкграунд 3 блокам?

Tags: html, css

Есть 3 секции, я всегда задавал 1 div который покрывал 3 секции и задавал ему 1 бекграунд, правильной ли такой подход?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: правильный, что вызвало у вас сомнения?

Comment: Незнаю) хотел проверить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать блоки одинаковой ширины (Если сетка Bootstrap,то к примеру col-lg-12(И таким образом все 3 блока)или в CSS сделать ширину классу этих блоков ( Width:900px; //к примеру//) , а изображения ( 3 как в примере ) сделать одинаковой ширины и формы ( К примеру 480x320, и так все три ) // Сделать это можно при помощи редактора фото к примеру Photoshop //